# jaspersoft studio book creation - data source

Tags: sql, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I'd like to create a report book in JS Studio (6.2.x) (with 2 already existing reports within the content section, without cover/toc/backcover).

The book-layout is needed as the included reports have different page formats (landscape, portrait) - and use their individual sql queries.

Is a sql query needed for the report book (as a shell) to generate only the included reports?

In case a query is needed, what should be the resultset of this query? 
(I mean in context of the included reports and their independent queries)

Comment: All you might need is a query that returns a single record, something like "select 1".

Comment: Thanks! Seems to work with a simple query "select 1 from dual"

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comment above, a simple query

```
select 1 from dual
```

helped.

Additionally parameter mapping from the book to the included reports needs to be considered.